# Cannot retrieve collection outside of the view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm making a simple list of people with option when clicking on person's name the Router will take a name as a parameter *'student/:name'* and find a right person's object in a collection. I instantiate collection in a `GroupView` class by fetching it from the server. And that's where the Error appears: to get the access to collection (so I can find right object) in my `viewStudent()` method in Router class, I'm making one more instance of `GroupView()`, and console shows an error and that's right, 'cause there're no objects in collection.

I cannot wrap my head around this, why in GroupView() I receive data from the server and my collection just works fine, but second time I instantiate `GroupView()` in a Router - there's no collection? Maybe there's any other way I can get access to the collection in my Router? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 var StudentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Volodya',
        lastName: 'Peterson',
        age: 22,
        gender: 'male'
    }
});

var StudentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: StudentModel,
    url: '/students.json'
});

var StudentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template($('#studentTpl').html()),

    events: {
        'click': function () {
            eventAggregator.trigger('student:selected', this.model);
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var GroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new StudentsCollection();
        this.collection.on('update', this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function (student) {
            var studentView = new StudentView({
                model: student
            });
            self.$el.append(studentView.render().el);
        });
        $('body').html(this.$el);
    }
});

var RouterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function () {
        var self = this;

        _.each(this.model.toJSON(), function (value) {
            self.$el.append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        });

        return this;
    }
});

var GroupController = function  () {
    this.start = function () {
        var groupView = new GroupView();
    };
};

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'student/:name': 'viewStudent'
    },

    index: function () {
        groupController.start();
    },

    viewStudent: function (name) {
        var groupView = new GroupView();
        var selectedStudent = groupView.collection.find(function (student) {
            return student.get('name') === name;
        });
        $('body').append((new RouterView({ model : selectedStudent})).render().el);
    }
});

var eventAggregator= _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),
    groupController;

$(function () {
    var router = new Router();

    groupController = new GroupController();
    Backbone.history.start();

    eventAggregator.on('student:selected', function (student) {
        var urlpath= 'student/'+ student.get('name');
        router.navigate(urlpath, {trigger: true});
    });
});
```

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call, it won't have returned from the server and populated the collection between your `new GroupView()` and `groupView.collection.find(...)` calls so the collection will be empty when you try to `find` something in it.

Comment: so making another AJAX call in Router in order to get a collection will be appropriate? (make fetch and inside of success function put all the functionality of viewStudent method)

Comment: You might be able to use the same collection depending on how the app is structured. Or just fetch the single model you need for that `RouterView` .